# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. not that typicaly

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I want to debug my code on my Device, but I got this problem.
I am using IntelliJ
Googled it, but doesn´t get a answer for this problem.
Don´t know where the Problem can be.
SDK Version of Android is 30. Don´t know what Version my Phone has.But it have Android 10
Exeption:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @424d75a1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

build.gradle in android

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle in android/app

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "de.justlutz.todoapp"
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        minSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.3')
}
```

don´t know what the problem is here

Answer (score 0):

solved!
first in gradle-wrapper.properties (root/android/gradle/wrapper)
i changed the distribuitonURL to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip` for a newer Version of gradle.

then I go into the build.gradle in the app path (root/android/app)
there I addded `minSdkVersion 19` to defaultConfig (class android)

The last thing I do, was going into the build.gradle in android (root/android)
there I upgraded the andorid gradle dependency (in buildscript Class) to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'` (the newest Version).

and in repositories in class buildscript and allprojects I added the google maven repository

```
maven {
url 'https://maven.google.com/'
name 'Google'}
```

Finaly I reloaded the gradle settings and all works fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).